# Unable to run KVM on Dell Inspiron

Tags: kvm-virtualization, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 13 (7368) and I'm trying to run AQEMU on any open source virtual machine.
I keep getting errors associated with `kvm not found` or `cannot save emulator KVM 0.14.X`, etc.
Is it possible to run KVM on this machine? Lubuntu runs just fine.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) may help you install KVM correctly on your system.

Comment: Thank you for responding Stormlord! I will go look at it now...

Comment: No good.  I Actually already  tried this one. AQEMU starts, but it won't successfully build a virtual machine. I get the impression that the system somehow prevents kvm from working.